# When/why to use sqlite with asp.net MVC/Webfoms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, webforms

I really dont know why people use sqlite. As i just gone through some Top voted sqlite question i can't get the point. So can someone suggest the point When/why to use sqlite with asp.net MVC/Webfoms?

**EDIT:**

Any good sample asp.net web application that uses sqlite for getting started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free. Lightweight. Local DB storage in file. Great for testing (in memory DB FTW). If you're using NHibernate, it's completely interchangeable with anything else (with a few exceptions that I've found). Using a local SQL Express DB requires all of the necessary SQL Express stuff to be installed on the server and be running as services. SQLite has no services that run.

If it meets your needs, go for it. If you need more horsepower, use something bigger.

Answer (score 2):

So you do not pay for SQL Server licence or don't have to cope with any deployment issues. All you need is a reference to one dll and a write access to one folder where your database file will be stored. The footprint is tiny: compare < 1MB with SQL Server Express installation.